# Как изменить ширину вкладки, чтобы надпись вошла полностью?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

Надпись во вкладке слишком длинная, поэтому появляется многоточие ...

Как изменить ширину вкладки, чтобы надпись вошла полностью?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, а для этого вопроса точно подходит метка "java"?)

Answer (score 0):

Навести курсор на правую границу вкладки, зажать левую кнопку мыши и потянуть вправо)